# Slate vs Swagger - Which is better and which have more options?

Tags: documentation, swagger, api-doc, swagger-editor

I have to document my API's. I have to use any one of them [Slate](https://github.com/tripit/slate) Or [Swagger](http://swagger.io/). I want to know which one have more options, pros and cons, which one is better.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Swagger and Slate serve two different purposes. Swagger is an attempt at a standardized way of describing a RESTful API (similar, for example, to [ApiBlueprint](https://apiblueprint.org/))

> Swagger is a JSON based API definition format, which allows for the description of REST APIs.

~ [API Design Tooling From Swagger](http://apievangelist.com/2014/02/25/api-design-tooling-from-swagger/)

Slate, on the other hand is a pretty theme for writing nice API docs.

1. The two are not mutually exclusive
2. Ideally, one should generate your slate documentation from your Swagger API description

The goal of Swagger is to provide a standard upon which others can build extensive tooling (for example: documentation, API explorers, mock servers, code generation, testing utilities etc.). See, for example: [Swagger Tooling](http://swagger.io/tools/)

More to your question: Some Slate tooling for swagger:

- Here is a [link to a Slate themed swagger UI](https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui)
- Here is a project that [generates Slate docs based on your Swagger definition](https://github.com/E96/swagger2slate)

So the two are not mutually exclusive, but to your direct question: Implementing Swagger will give you more options and greater flexibility (was well as the ability to also generate Slate documentation).

Comment: Swagger2Slate is no-longer maintained and seems to have several outstanding issues. https://github.com/mermade/widdershins is a Node.js  based Swagger/OpenApi spec to Slate markdown converter. Disclosure, I am the author.

Comment: Even with different purposes hatcommunity switched from swagger to slant for example: http://forum.hatcommunity.org/t/api-documentation-publishing-slate-vs-swagger/69

Answer (score 5):

**About Slate:**
-   API documentation Template/Framework 
-   looks good
-   ease of use
-   Syntax highlighting
-   Language Specific – Tabbed
-   Page Search
-   3 columned customizable layout
-   We can create table
-   Scrollable links to each and every blocks/methods/headings
-   Alert Facility [3 types] – warning, success, notice
-   Tables for http error codes
-   Markdown syntax
-   We can use Site logo
-   [Demo](http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/)

**About Swagger:**
-   It gives us API access inside the docs itself, where we can check the response for any particular request.
-   It gives a clear picture of API responds with their parameters and options.
-   YAML based format
-   Not suited for hypermedia API
-   There is no Design tooling for Swagger
-   Responses are in XML or JSON
-   Swagger JS -- JavaScript library to connect to swagger-enabled APIs via browser or nodejs
-   Swagger Node Express -- Swagger module for node.js express module
-   It has swagger UI framework
-   [Demo](http://petstore.swagger.io/)

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view, those tools have very different purposes. Swagger is a description language, while slate is just for documentation.

I've used swagger to create a descriptionn, from which i can autogenerate different clients for my API, even autogenerate documentation.

You can also create Markdown from the swagger spec, and the use those markdowns in Slate. [1]

[1] https://github.com/RobWin/swagger2markup

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Neoecos. I have already started documenting using Swagger.

Comment: @SaribanD'Cl if the answer was useful, please accept the answer greeen ✓

Answer (score 1):

I make slate-flask(https://github.com/AhnSeongHyun/slate-flask) based on python-flask.

features:

- Configuration File(config.json) : Set title, programming language for example codes using config.json base on JSON Format. Also set the path of the API documents and TOC(Table of contents).
- Support Multi-API documents : Original Slate support one API document based on Markdown format. But slate-flask support multi-API documents for efficient management and amount of documents using TOC(index.json).
- Support dynamic changes of documents : You can reflect the changes of API documents without restarting server. When web page refresh, if exist changes, slate-flask reload API documents. Users only focus on writing API documents.